# Как найти в коде все классы, которые реализуют определенный интерфейс?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Возможно ли такое в IDE без решарпера и подобных? Конечно, можно ввести в глобальный поиск имя интерфейса, но:

- в проекте есть интерфейсы, у которых имя совпадает с существующим во фрэймворке (проект очень старый, когда то в ФВ их не было)
- я найду очень много лишнего по имени интерфейса, помимо определений классов

Comment: Интерфейс не наследуют, его реализуют )

Comment: @Suvitruf, спасибо за замечание. Но лучше бы за ним следовал ответ )

Comment: Я с решарпером только под VS пишу )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правой кнопкой по имени интерфейса -> "Найти все ссылки".

Там же будет сочетание клавиш для быстрого вызова этой команды, если оно назначено.

В описанном выше способе покажутся все ссылки, включая объявление свойств, полей и прочих членов классов.

Для поиска только классов, реализующих интерфейс можно использовать следующий способ:
Правой кнопкой по имени интерфейса -> "Показать на карте кода". Далее на карте кода: правой кнопкой по блоку интерфейса -> "Показать производные типы"

Comment: Вторая проблема остается при этом

Comment: Согласен.

Тогда по-другому. Правой кнопкой по имени интерфейса -> "Показать на карте кода". Далее на карте кода: правой кнопкой по блоку интерфейса -> "Показать производные типы"

Comment: Добавьте это в ответ, пожалуйста